# How to start PowerShell in a new window from .bat and run a .ps1 without exiting the console?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to have a .bat file that

- opens a PowerShell console in a new window
- and runs a .ps1 script
- and does not exit and close the PowerShell console.

My batch file contains the following line:

```
start powershell.exe -Command "&'D:\MyToolkit\ToolKit.ps1'"
```

However, it closes the PowerShell after running the script.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: `start powershell -noexit -file "D:\MyToolkit\ToolKit.ps1"`

Comment: Thanks! Worked! It did not work when I put it in the end but when I put it before -Commandit worked

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
start powershell -noexit -file "D:\MyToolkit\ToolKit.ps1"
```

Also,

Change the `-Command` to `-File` as this is what you need

Answer (score 5):

Not just for the original poster of this question, but for others who might land here looking for answers, the help system is very useful and seems to be often overlooked.

Using *command /?* or in `PowerShell` the `get-help` and `get-help -full` commands are every useful.

You probably could have answered your own question by reading the help for the command you wanted to run, `powershell` in this case.

```
PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-Mta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?

-NoExit
    Does not exit after running startup commands.

...

-File
    Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
    functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
    current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
    File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
    typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
    as the script file path followed by the script parameters.
```

> -NoExit -- Does not exit after running startup commands.
>
> -File -- ... File must be the last parameter in the command ...