# Start PowerShell with -NoExit not working

Tags: powershell

Need to launch several jobs in PowerShell, but they should be in different sessions. So to launch one, one could use:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-command &{Get-Process}","-noexit","-noprofile"
```

But the new window closes as soon as the command finishes. Even though I'm using `-NoExit` parameter. Acording to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112419/how-to-start-powershell-in-a-new-window-from-bat-and-run-a-ps1-without-exiting), this should work. Even tried to block the window, by waiting for an user input, but it just closes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the command parameters are named, position is still critical (see PowerShell.exe /?):

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-noprofile", "-command &{Get-Process}"
```

Comment: Didn't know that. Thought that naming the parameters excluded the necessity of them being positioned in a specific place.

Comment: @Syphirint that is (almost always) true _within_ powershell (the notable exception being when you use [ValueFromRemainingArguments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)), and often on the command line as well but an .exe can define its parameters any way it wants. In this case `-command` needs to be at the end for a similar reason: it would be ambiguous whether an additional parameter was part of the command or not.

Comment: It's really only that it needs -command to be last because it has the most vague content. The simplest way to avoid worrying about "where's the end of command?" is to make it last and read to the end of input.

Comment: Plus 1 for the info on having to place `-command` / `-c` and its argument(s) last, but two asides:

Comment: While passing arguments as as an _array_ to `-ArgumentList` is _conceptually_ the best approach, it is unfortunately ill-advised due to a long-standing bug in `Start-Process`, still present as of this writing (v7.1)  - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576). For now, using a _single_ string comprising _all_ arguments, enclosed in _embedded_ `"..."` quoting as necessary, is the only robust approach. As discussed in the linked GitHub issue, an `-ArgumentArray` parameter that supports robust array-based argument passing may be introduced in the future.

Comment: There's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.