# PowerShell script to open a new PowerShell window and run command

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm looking for a way to write a script which is able to open a new PowerShell window and to run command. E.g. I'd like to launch PowerShell, in this window I need to run a script able to open a new PowerShell window inside which the command pwd is executed.

Comment: Use the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet - on Windows, it runs the specified executable in a new window by default (on Unix, the command invariably runs in the same window).

Comment: Hello @mklement0 I tried to run the command Start-Process powershell.exe pwd, but the new PowerShell screen appears and disappears quickly. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This does the job, you forgot -NoExit

    `Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit "& {pwd}"'`

Don't forget to check help

   `powershell /?, Get-Help Start-Process`

Comment: Also just found a good explanation of why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831008/start-powershell-with-noexit-not-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try on of this Commands

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit"  



 Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-noprofile", "-command &{Get-Location}"
```

to start the Window maximized us the Parameter `-WindowStyle Maximized`

Provide more Code for further Information

Comment: Plus 1 for the need for `-noexit` to keep the new window open (only needed if `-Command` / `-c` are also specified), but two asides:

Comment: While passing arguments as an _array_ to `-ArgumentList` _conceptually_ the best approach, it is unfortunately ill-advised due to a long-standing bug in `Start-Process`, still present as of this writing (v7.1)  - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576). For now, using a _single_ string comprising _all_ arguments, enclosed in _embedded_ `"..."` quoting as necessary, is the only robust approach. As discussed in the linked GitHub issue, an `-ArgumentArray` parameter that supports robust array-based argument passing may be introduced in the future.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: *Correction to the first comment: `-noexit` is only needed if one of the following parameters are also specified: `-Command` (`-c`), `-EncodeCommand`,  `-File`.